# Как называется эта штука?

Tags: словарь

Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу подобрать слово для обозначения детали дверного замка. Попытался найти её название на тематических сайтах, но безрезультатно. Быть может здесь кто-то подскажет правильное слово?

С внутренней стороны самого обычного кодового замка (такие часто используются на подъездах), для того,чтобы выйти, необходимо потянуть в сторону задвижку до щелчка.

Вопрос: как правильно эту задвижку назвать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее *рычаг* или *щеколда* в зависимости от типа замка.

Comment: Спасибо. Выберу щеколду.